# Select the element once with the lowest value through JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have a table like that

```
Item1 10
Item2 20
Item1 40
Item2 5
```

I would like to select all the elements once (not repeated value) with the lowest price. For instance

```
Item1 10 e Item2 5
```

Do you have any idea? I have tried to use DISTINCT but at the same time I can't use MIN

So something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT(o.name) FROM Object o GROUP BY MIN(o.value)
```

Comment: ..and DB Server name is?

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` Item Name

Comment: Edited to show how it should work

Comment: select min(o.value), o.itemname from Object o group by o.itemname;

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your columns and table name but try this :

`select o.name, min(o.value) from Object o group by o.name`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT I.ITEM_NAME, I.PRICE FROM ITEMS I
GROUP BY I.ITEM_NAME, I.PRICE
HAVING I.PRICE = (SELECT MIN(PRICE) FROM ITEMS WHERE ITEM_NAME = I.ITEM_NAME)
```

Use your column and table names.